# Classify the abelian groups of order 81, 144 and 216

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Classify the abelian groups of order n, 2n, 4n

Comment: i tried to write 81 = 3^4, 144 = (3^2).(2^4), 216 = (2^3).(3^4) but i don't where to to go next

Answer (score 2):

Here, you will want to use the theorem of structure of finite abelian groups, that is: Every abelian finite group is isomorphic to a group of the form:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{m_2} \times\mathbb{Z}_{m_3} \times... \times\mathbb{Z}_{m_n}$$

In which $m_i$ divides $m_{i-1}$, and abviously the product of all $m_i$ has to be the order of the group.

So you have to find possible combinations of numbers $m_i$ that meet the above conditions. For example $81=3^4$, just find the combinations.

Now, a further result that will allow you to not repeat any group is this one:

If $G$ is a group of the form $G=G_1\times G_2$, then both of the next things are equivalent

1. G is cyclic
2. $\gcd(|G_1|,|G_2|)=1$

This means for example, if we have groups of order 18, then the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ will be the same as $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$

With this results you should be able to classify all the abelian groups of those orders.

Sadly, I've studied this from books (really good books), written in spanish and I can't give references to the proves of these results in english, but I suppose that you will find them in any elementary group theory book. Maybe someone wants to comment with some references.

P.S.: As you're not directly asking anything, I haven't explicitly solved the exercise that looks a lot like homework. If you have any quetion regarding some of the results you don't understand, then ask it.

Comment: For references in english, I think Lang or Dummit & Foote would have this, and much more.

Comment: @arbautjc Thank you for completing the answer

Comment: thanks for your response but you said mi divides mi−1 but 2 doesn't divide 9 as in Z2 x Z9

Comment: The "combinations" of positive integers you mention are called "partitions" of a natural number:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: @Theo You're right, but that just means you still can reduce it to a combination of that kind, in this case the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ The second proposition is actually contained in the first one.

Comment: @DonAntonio That wikipedia article talks about decomposing numbers as sums of integers. Is it also called partition if we do it in factors of a multiplication?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, @MyUserIsThis, but you have to take all the partitions of every prime's power and then multiply them all. Thus for example, as $\,144=2^4\cdot 3^2\,$, and since there are $\;5\;$ partitions for four and $\,2\,$ for two, there are $\,5\cdot 2=10\,$ abelian groups of order $\,144\,$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I know that, I just said that in the article of the wikipedia you sent here, it says that partitions are decompositions of a as sums: 4=3+1=2+2=1+2+1... I just asked if when they are multiplications of prime factors, not sums, like it's here, it's also called a partition...

Comment: The partitions are of *natural numbers*, @MyUserIsThis, and it doesn't matter whether you use them as powers, in sums, in products.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, then, the article clearly says: "way of writing n as a sum of positive integers"... but whatever, it's just names.